# Connecting to sql azure from ssms throw exception 'sys.configurations'

Tags: ssms, azure-sql-database

Connecting to Sql Server Azure from MSSQL Server MGMT Studio, following exception occures :

```
Cannot connect to xxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net

An exception occured while executing a Transact-SQL Statement or batch.
   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

sql management studio connection to windows azure invalid exception object name 
'sys.configurations'
```

Any clue ?

```
And here's the whole message : Cannot connect to ndkkyxvogj.database.windows.net.

===================================

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteWithResults(String sqlCommand) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ObjectExplorer.CheckDacAndSmo(SqlConnection sqlConnection) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ObjectExplorer.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()

===================================

Invalid object name 'sys.configurations'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=11.00.9164&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=208&LinkId=20476

Server Name: ndkkyxvogj.database.windows.net Error Number: 208 Severity: 16 State: 1 Line Number: 17

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteWithResults(String sqlCommand)
```

Comment: What's the version of SSMS? From that version number, it looks like 2014. If that's correct, you may be out of luck, or you should report it as a bug on Connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there can be couple of issues -

1. Firewall : You will need to add your local IP range to the allowed SQL Azure Firewall rules. Refer to : [How to: Configure the Server-Level Firewall Settings (Windows Azure SQL Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/jj553530%28v=azure.100%29)
2. You are using older/unsupported version of SSMS. If yes, then upgrade to the latest version (e.g SSMS 2008R2 - build 10.50.** Refer : [SQL Azure July 2011 Service Release](https://web.archive.org/web/20140502102332/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/07/13/announcing-sql-azure-july-2011-service-release.aspx)

   [image]
3. You might be hitting - [Invalid object name ‘sys.configurations’. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 208)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ramaprasanna/invalid-object-name-sys-configurations-microsoft-sql-server-error-208)

Comment: It's worth noting that if you do need to connect to Azure with a version of SSMS 2008 that is an older build than 10.50, then you can open a query window to another server (eg. localhost), then right click on the query window and connect to Azure via the "Connect -> Change Connection" context menu option. This doesn't exhibit the error.